# Open Android App when Push Notification is received

Tags: android, notifications

When a notification is received my android app opens up when the notification is clicked from notification center but along with that I want to open up my sliding drawer also..
Here is my code

IntentReceiver.class  (custom push receiver)

```
     String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED)) {
          Log.i(logTag, "User clicked notification. Message: " + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_ALERT));

        //  logPushExtras(intent);
          if(!MainActivity.active){
          Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
          launch.setClass(UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
          launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext().startActivity(launch);
          }

  }
}
```

and this is in main activity..

```
public static boolean active;
```

I want to add the following

```
 final SlidingDrawer banner = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);
        banner.animateOpen();
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it..
Open up sliding drawer when app is opened through notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear. As I understand it, you have a main activity that can be opened either from the launcher, or from a notification intent. You wish to open the Sliding Drawer *only* when the activity is started by a notification intent, but not when it is started from the launcher.
If that is the case, you merely need to use `Intent.putExtra()` when creating your `launch` intent, then check for the extra when your activity opens.

Add to `IntentReceiver.class`, before `startActivity(launch)`:

```
launch.putExtra("notification", "true");
```

In `Main Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutfile);

    final SlidingDrawer banner = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String extra = intent.getStringExtra("notification");

    if(extra != null && extra.equals("true") && (intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == 0)
    {
        banner.animateOpen();
    }
}
```

The `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` check is to ensure that the intent is coming from your receiver, and is not the Recent cached intent.

Just as an FYI, SlidingDrawer has been deprecated.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. but you have guessed it right. The code works as I wanted. Thank You!